# Set App Image Folder as Default Folder for Events like "Selecting an Image from Gallery"

Tags: android, android-gallery

**Objective**: I want to set my app image folder as the default folder instead of the android "All Images" folder for the events like "Selecting an image from gallery". E.g: Attaching an image in email.

Android Version: 8.0.0(Oreo)

I am not getting any docs or any similar question so please help me with this issue, is there any setting or metadata to be sent while creating the image folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a "default folder" in Android, assuming that by "folder" you mean "filesystem directory".

There is no "All Images" folder in Android, again assuming that by "folder" you mean "filesystem directory".

With regards to "Selecting an image from gallery", a gallery is a type of app. There are thousands of gallery apps, both pre-installed and user-installed. Those apps were written by other programmers. What they do in response to an `ACTION_PICK` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request is up to them.

So, for a few reasons, what you want is not possible.